# Add ajax load more function using WP API

Tags: posts, categories, ajax, rest-api

I want to create a load more function using ajax for a post category. I've followed [this article](https://www.weichieprojects.com/blog/ajax-load-more-posts-wordpress/#!) on how to proceed, but after I add the function to register the endpoint, it will give me a 404 error about the second page that didn't exists.

Is there any error in the code or another way without using plugins to implement this in WP? (I'm an experienced PHP developer but I don't use wordpress a lot and it's all new for me for some aspects).

functions.php

```
    <?php
    add_action('rest_api_init', 'portfolio_ajax_api');
      function portfolio_ajax_api(){
        register_rest_route( 'portfolio', '/all-posts', array(
          'methods' => 'GET',
          'callback' => 'get_portfolio'
        ));
      }

  function get_showcase($request){
    $posts_data = array();
    $paged = $request->get_param('page');
    $paged = (isset($paged) || !(empty($paged))) ? $paged : 1;
    $posts = get_posts( array(
      'post_type'       => 'post',
      'status'          => 'published',
      'posts_per_page'  => 9,
      'orderby'         => 'post_date',
      'order'           => 'DESC',
      'paged'           => $paged
    ));

    foreach($posts as $post){
      $id = $post->ID;
      $post_thumbnail = (has_post_thumbnail($id)) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id) : null;
      $post_cat = get_the_category($id);
      $featured = (get_field('project_featured', $id)) ? true : false;

      $posts_data[] = (object)array(
        'id' => $id,
        'slug' => $post->post_name,
        'type' => $post->post_type,
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        'featured_img_src' => $post_thumbnail,
        'featured' => $featured,
        'category' => $post_cat[0]->cat_name
      );
    }
    return $posts_data;
}
?>
```

template file:

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'status'        => 'published',
  'category_name' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'=> 1,
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'paged'         => $paged
));

?>

<div class="card-columns">
<?php if( $portfolio->have_posts() ): while( $portfolio->have_posts() ): $portfolio->the_post();  ?>
    <div class="card hide">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" id="case-studies">
          <div class="overlay"><h4 class="text-center" id="client-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div>
      </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" id="show-more">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="load-more"><?php _e('Visualizza altro') ?></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
    $('#load-more').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var pull_page = 1;
  var jsonFlag = true;

  if(jsonFlag){
    pull_page++;

    $.getJSON("/u/wp-json/portfolio/all-posts?page=" + pull_page, function(data){
        if(data.length){
        pull_page++;

        console.log(data.length);

        $.each(data, function(i, item){
          var html = '<div class="card">';
          html += '<a href="'+ item.permalink +'">';
          html += '<img class="card-img-top w-100" src="'+ item.featured_img_src +'" id="case-studies" />';
          html += '<div class="overlay"><h4 class="text-center" id="client-name">'+ item.title +'</h4></div>';
          html += '</a>';
          html += '</div>';
          $('body').find('.card-columns')
          .append(html);
        });
      }
      else{
        jsonFlag = false;
      }
    }).done(function(data){
      if(data.length >= 4){
        jsonFlag = true;
      }
      else{
        jsonFlag = false;
      }
    });
    }

  }); // end load more
```

EDIT: 
I've solved the issue about the 404 error, It was due to the fact that wordpress is installed inside a subfolder of my local development server, so I've changed the url to match the correct route. 
Now the problem is that I need to display all posts with the `$.each()` loop inside a bootstrap card and I can't figure out how to proceed correctly. this because the html code for my cards is using the php wordpress loop generated by the wp_query on page load.

Comment: sounds like the parameter for paging `$request->get_param('page')` is not set properly? put it in your return and check, if its correct / hardcode another value just for testing..

Comment: @honk31 I've solved, the url requested from `getJSON()` was wrong. The problem now I need to fix is how to show inside my bootstrap cards the json response. I want to use the `$.each()` function but with no success!

Comment: well, how does your response look like, whats the issue..?

Comment: the response log all the posts on page 2,3 ecc.. About the response part there is no problem, I have updated the code with the loop I'm using. The problem is on displaying all the items correctly

Comment: sorry, but its not clear, what the issue is. when you append val, than you have issues with the display? in what form?

Comment: the issue is that the script load always the same posts.

Comment: sorry, but what you say makes no sense to me. in your previous comment, you said "About the response part there is no problem", the display is the issue. but now you say, that they are all the same..?

Comment: I wasn't clear in my comment. I've implemented the function following the article linked in the post. Initially I had a problem with the callback function, but I've solved. Then I've fixed a problem with the card creation inside the DOM, now I need to fix the posts loading, the issue is related to the loading after I've clicked the load more button, If there are 8 posts in the database and I want to display four of them at time, It will load the next four posts in page 2, but it will continue loading the posts also if the pages are only two. I want to check and stop this beahviour

Comment: as far as i see it, you are not updating your pull_page variable. wordpress will not load the same results of page 2, if you request page 3, even if page 3 was empty..

Comment: @honk31 can you suggest me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem, I was made a mistake with the variable `pull_page` that is inside the click event. I've moved the variable outside the event and now all works fine. Here is the updated code!

```
var pull_page = 1;
var jsonFlag = true;

$('#load-more').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if(jsonFlag){
    pull_page++;

    $.getJSON("/u/wp-json/portfolio/all-posts?page=" + pull_page, function(data){
        if(data.length){
        pull_page++;

        console.log(data.length);

        $.each(data, function(i, item){
          var html = '<div class="card">';
          html += '<a href="'+ item.permalink +'">';
          html += '<img class="card-img-top w-100" src="'+ item.featured_img_src +'" id="case-studies" />';
          html += '<div class="overlay"><h4 class="text-center" id="client-name">'+ item.title +'</h4></div>';
          html += '</a>';
          html += '</div>';
          $('body').find('.card-columns')
          .append(html);
        });
      }
      else{
        jsonFlag = false;
      }
    }).done(function(data){
      if(data.length >= 4){
        jsonFlag = true;
      }
      else{
        jsonFlag = false;
      }
    });
    }

  }); // end load more
```

Comment: ..told you so :)
but what i see here is, that you increase pull_page twice..? looks wrong to me.. hopefully it works, as intended..